# what to use instead of ActiveXObject to make it cross browser compatible

Tags: javascript, activexobject

My code uses `ActiveXObject` to send request. But this only works on IE as ActiveXObject is not compatible with other browser. What would be the best alternative to use instead of `ActiveXObject` on the following 2 example code snippet to make it work in other browsers?

```
var oSendDoc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
oSendDoc.async = false;
oSendDoc.loadXML( sRequestXML );
```

Second:

```
var m_oServerHTTP = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP");
m_oServerHTTP.send( oRequestXML );
```

Comment: Look up polyfills, which can handle browser compatibility for you while you make standard async calls.

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with MS-only APIs, but fast reading [msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml?view=netframework-4.7.2), the first one is just a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

So you could replace your first block with

```js
var sRequestXML = '<item><name>wrench</name></item>';
var oSendDoc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString( sRequestXML , 'text/xml');

console.log(oSendDoc.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

For the second one, an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is the probable equivalent, but we'd need to see the `oRequestXML` config object to show you a complete example.